# Connect Smooch with agent's platform

Tags: smooch, supportkit

Just two questions, Smooch has a live agent's platform? or it should connect to other Zendesk products like Zendesk Support?

If Zendesk Support is needed, there is a way to connect it automatically or I need to connect it through webhooks?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options when using Sunshine Conversations:

1. Link your existing Zendesk Support subdomain to your Sunshine Conversations account (contact support@zendesk.com to start the migration process)
2. Use an official integration from the Marketplace to link it to another Business System: https://app.smooch.io/integrations/categories/business-systems
3. Build an integration to any other Business System using our APIs: https://docs.smooch.io/guide/api-quickstart/